# How can I declare a function that takes in a function as parameter in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I want to declare a function that takes in a function(the function also takes a element as parameter) and a list as parameters in Scheme

but the is line of code gives me error
(define (function funct(x),l)

Comment: Ok: what's the error that you see?  It's often helpful to look at the error message content and see if it says anything comprehensible.  Also, see http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_three.html for examples of writing functions that can consume functions.

Comment: define: not an identifier, identifier with default, or keyword for procedure argument in: (x)

Comment: So the compiler is trying to say at this point that there's a syntax error in the definition, and it's probably near *(x)*.  See João Silva's answer; he or she shows an example.  Fundamentally, if you're writing a function with arguments, no matter what those arguments are, you give each argument a plain name: no other special syntax is necessary.  *(define (func arg1 arg2 ... argN) ...)* no matter what kind of thing an *arg* is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme, functions are [first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen). Thus, you can pass a function as a parameter to another function, just like you do with any other symbol. There's no such thing as the `function` keyword.

For example, to define a function called `map` that takes a function as an argument, and applies it to every member of the list, you could use:

```
(define (map f l)
  (if (null? l)
      l
      (cons (f (car l)) (map f (cdr l)))))
```

Then, if you had a function called `add1` that you wanted to pass to `map`:

```
(define (add1 x)
  (+ x 1))

(map add1 '(1 2 3))
```

The result would be `(2 3 4)`.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/clone/V79vv)**.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme does not allow you to specify the parameter types in the function definition.  The best you can do is

```
(define my-func(func . args)
```

Which will give you the first argument in the **func** parameter and all the rest in a list in **args**.  You can then check the type of ** func **, if you want, before applying it to the args.

```
(cond
  ((procedure? func) (func args))
  (else (report some kind of error however you want)))
```